# how to reload ng-view with new data?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a situation to refresh the page as per the user search results. I have a fixed navbar with search bar. and also i am changing the view using `ng-view`. when my url is '`localhost/index`' and when i search for any location means my url will change to 'localhost/searchresults' using the `"$location.url()"` and i will get what i want. The problem is, when i am in the same url `"localhost/searchresults"` and search for any location means its not working. How to do that????

Edit:
Actually both are at different controller. search bar is at one controller and search results is on another controller. that's why i am using `$location.url()` to change my ng-view and controller.

Updated:
This is the answer. "$route.reload()".

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To force angular to re-render the current page, you can use:

```
$route.reload();
```

Comment: `$route.reload();` i used on controller to reload the data but it can not work it thrown an error like `$route is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

> @pradip Talaviya

You might not have added the **$route** service to be used by the controller.

Example:

```
app.controller("homectrl", function($rootScope, $scope, $route) {
    ...here you can use $route
});
```